# Sum implies null product. True?

Tags: sums-of-squares

Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{C}$. Assuming that $x+y+z=x^2+y^2+z^2=0$, is it true that $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\left(x^2+y^2+z^2 \right)^2 = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + 2 \left(x^2y^2+y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 \right)$$
This implies we have
$$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = -2 \left(x^2y^2+y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 \right) \,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$
Similarly, we have
$$\left(x+y+z\right)^4 = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + 4(x^3(y+z)+y^3(x+z)+z^3(x+y)) + 6(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2) + 12xyz(x+y+z)$$
This implies
$$0 = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + 4(x^3(-x)+y^3(-y)+z^3(-z)) + 6(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)$$
Hence,
$$x^4+y^4+z^4 = 2(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2) \,\,\,\, (\clubsuit)$$
Comparing $(\spadesuit)$ and $(\clubsuit)$, we obtain
$$\boxed{x^4+y^4+z^4 = 0 = x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2}$$